# Twenty Eleven theme-options error

Tags: errors

I was trying to add Google Analytics and added it to the theme-option page by accident when I went to remove the added info I received the following error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/content/07/9999407/html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/inc/theme-options.php on line 416

Is there a way to restore the twenty eleven theme-option?
Self taught and not doing well apparently

Comment: now the website won't even come up to correct the error how do I update the theme or add a new theme?

Comment: Are you saying you directly edited the theme-options.php file? If so simply download the theme to your local machine; them FTP the file to your server. That will restore it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to login over FTP, or via some file manager supplied by your host (cPanel and Plesk have built in FTP-like file managers), and replace that file with a clean one. After which, don't use the file editor. It is dangerous, like working on an airplane while it is in the air.

Comment: In this particular case the editor isn't important. Simply shouldn't edit files on a production environment.

Comment: @Stephen, yes, that too... absolutely. I assumed the asker was using the editor given that these problem are easily undone if you are using FTP and impossible if you are using the editor.